# javac: no source files when trying to use javac with -classpath

Tags: java, mysql, classpath, javac

I am trying to connect MySQL server with Java. But when I try to compile the file on Windows it gives this error.

```
PS D:\connectivity> javac -classpath D:\connectivity\mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar;. Check.java
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: posted command works fine for me... are you sure that is the exact command? maybe missing a space or using a *special space*?

Comment: @user16320675 It is exactly the same. I copied it directly from my terminal. Do you think the problem might be with javac?

Comment: I don't think it is `javac`.. I wonder the `PS` at the very start

Comment: @user16320675 PS stands for PowerShell. Ill try to run it in cmd

Comment: It was because I was using PowerShell, command works fine on CMD. Thanks

Comment: @user16320675 if you answer this question ill select it as accepted answer.

Comment: The command should work in PS if you quote the class path string. In cmd, `echo a;b` outputs `a;b`, but in PS you have to type `echo "a;b"` to get the same output. In PowerShell, the semicolon is a command separator.